# Flutter camera preview didn't show up before hot reload

Tags: android, flutter, android-camera

Long story short, I use flutter's camera dependency. Everything works fine until it's time for the camera preview to show up, but it doesn't even though the camera hardware is activated already (I use emulator so I can see the webcam indicator lamp is active). When I hot reload it, the preview shows. I tried programmatical force rebuild but it doesn't work because the problem lays on the value of camera controller (that's what the output says).

Without further ado, here's my snippet

```
if (camCtrl == null || !camCtrl.value.isInitialized) {
      return LoadingOverlay();
    } else if (camCtrl.value.isInitialized) {
      return Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: displayWidth(context),
            child: camCtrl.value.isInitialized
                ? CameraPreview(camCtrl)
                : LoadingOverlay(),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
            child: FloatingActionButton(child: Icon(Icons.camera), onPressed: () {}),
          )
        ],
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the mishandling of Futures.

Try to go through your Code again.

I guess you have missed the **await keyboard** somewhere.

Also, you can use a **FutureBuilder** here.

If none helps, refer this - https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/picture-using-camera

Answer (score 0):

After initializing the camera, you need to use setState to update the UI.